# increase in number after button click

Tags: jquery, button, click

I am trying make a math quiz. It has 10 questions.

2 random numbers is generated. user is to key in the answer in the textbox. Upon clicking check, a pop up window will show correct or wrong.

The score will increase depending on the correct or wrong answer.

The question number start from Question 1/10 and end after Question 10/10.

Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var num1=0;
var num2=0;
var sum=0;
var right=0;
var wrong=0;
var QNUM=1;

function random()
{
    num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    $("#number1").html(num1);
    $("#number2").html(num2);
    sum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
}

function checking()
{
    $(":button").click(function () {
    var text = $(":text").val();

    if(text == sum)
    {  
        alert("correct");
        right = right+1; 
        $("#correctScore").html(right); 
    }
    else    
    {  
        alert("wrong");
        wrong = wrong+1;
        $("#wrongScore").html(wrong);
    }
    random();
    text = $(":text").val('');
    });    
}


random();
checking();
 });
```

I have written my question number with this code:

```
$("#question").html("Question " + QNUM + "/10");
QNUM=QNUM+1;
```

Where can I put this in my code, so after user answered the first question, the QNUM will increase and stop after the 10 question?

Answer (score 0):

it seems your code misses the iterator that will control running 10 times the `random()` and `checking()` functions.

you can have a good perspective of its present and future here for later
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

for now, try :

```
   while (QNUM < 11) {
    random();
    checking();
  }
```

and include the snippet below into the checkinh() function.

```
$("#question").html("Question " + QNUM + "/10");
 QNUM=QNUM+1;
```

`

Comment: Hi, I have tried the while loop method. Everytime I run the html, Firefox will hang. It'll stop responding then the pop up with "stop script or continue" error will come out. what is wrong with writing script with while loop?

Comment: make sure you include ` QNUM=QNUM+1;` inside the while loop. take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp for more examples.

Comment: Yes I did. And still there is a script error asking me to stop script. 
Anyway, i went to look at .each() and added it into my code. But how do I make the number show one by one, instead of 1 then run through all the number to 10 straight away?

Answer (score 0):

With the advice from kasper, I went to look up the .each() and added into the end of the checking(). I delcare the var QNUM as this:

```
 var QNUM = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

This is the part which I added to the end of the checking()

```
 jQuery.each(QNUM, function(index, value){
 $("#question").html("Question " + parseInt(value) + "/10");
 });
```

So now my entire checking() look like this.

```
function checking()
{
    $(":button").click(function () {
    var text = $(":text").val();

    if(text == sum)
    {  
        alert("correct");
        right = right+1; 
        $("#correctScore").html(right); 
    }
    else    
    {  
        alert("wrong");
        wrong = wrong+1;
        $("#wrongScore").html(wrong);
    }
    random();
    jQuery.each(QNUM , function(index, value){
            $("#question").html("Question " + parseInt(value) + "/10");
        });
    text = $(":text").val('');
    });    
}
```

But the QNUM run straight from 1 all the way to 10 without showing 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

How can make the value show 1 by 1 after checking the right and wrong answer?